# mysql rows order recalculate

Tags: mysql

assume we have the table:

```
announces_id    announces_pos   announces_title
```

How to recalculate all announces_pos by single query?
example: 
set announces_pos to 3 on id 2, all next rows(announces_pos > 3) should to be recalculated

Comment: Re calculated how? Or how did you arrive at the value 3 for id 2?

Comment: This question is not clear (at least for me).

Comment: It is never mind, assume you have announces_pos = 100 for id 2, when user change it to 50, we need to increase all rows announces_pos's between 50 and 100

Comment: @Joeeee I think you should use trigger: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to old position. Than increase all positions between the old and the new one by 1.

```
DO @old_pos:=announces_pos FROM announces WHERE announces_id = 2;
UPDATE announces SET announces_pos = IF(announces_id = 2, 3, announces_pos + 1) WHERE announces_pos BETWEEN 3 AND @old_pos;
```

Comment: can you explain please what does it mean: IF(announces_id = 2, 3, announces_pos + 1)

Comment: It incements announces_id with 1 like `announces_pos = announces_pos + 1`, except for announces_id 3 where is does `announces_pos = 3`.